# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Poker Stack Exchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://poker.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Definition of "lead"](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/definition-of-lead)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What if you get a straight flush on flop?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-if-you-get-a-straight-flush-on-flop)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Start playing NL Hold'em or Limit Hold'em?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/start-playing-nl-holdem-or-limit-holdem)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Strategy Against Aggressive, Maniacal Player](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/strategy-against-aggressive-maniacal-player)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Quantifying the amount of luck required to win a tournament](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/quantifying-the-amount-of-luck-required-to-win-a-tournament)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the D on table and the terms defining players?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/what-is-the-d-on-table-and-the-terms-defining-players)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Joining an offline poker league - can being new be used to my advantage?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/joining-an-offline-poker-league-can-being-new-be-used-to-my-advantage)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Difference in strategies with stakes?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/difference-in-strategies-with-stakes)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Systematic all-in](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/systematic-all-in)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Who has the higher hand: 44 vs. A2 on a JJKK2 board?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/who-has-the-higher-hand-44-vs-a2-on-a-jjkk2-board)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)